# ftp server over internet using different port

Tags: networking, internet, ftp

I want to access my ftp server over the internet. I run it on Debian, I changed the port to 201, and my local ip is `192.168.1.3`.

I can access it from any computer on my network through `ftp://192.168.1.3:201`. I see the login page, I login with my linux user account and can see my files.

To make it public, I setup a port mapping on my router for port 201. However now, when I try `ftp://mypublicip:201`, it shows me the login page, but when I enter the login, it keeps loading forever without showing my files.

Strangely, when I run it over the default port (21), it works fine.

Can anyone tell me what is the problem here?

Answer (score 0):

First off, don't use ftp.  It is insecure and really crappy (who needs 30 ports to transfer a file?)  The problem you're seeing is most likely due to the fact that ftp uses multiple ports.  One for the connection, a second (or third, fourth, etc) for data transfers.  This includes transfers of file lists.

The other possibility is that the browser is dropping the port reference.  Internet Explorer has a really bad habit of this.  Once you log in, many times it renames the URL from `ftp://user:pass@host` to just `ftp://host` and then since the URL doesn't specify a name or pass any longer, attempts to log you in anonymously.  The same could be happening with the port, but I don't know about the browser you're using and if that's a possibility.

My suggestion is to NOT USE FTP first off.  Use ssh.  It's encrypted.  FTP is sending your password over the public internet in plain text, just FYI.  I recommend the below URL for other reasons.

http://mywiki.wooledge.org/FtpMustDie

Comment: i solved it i map port range 8000 to 8010 from my router and then configure the ftp server to use these passive range for data transfer, I will search about ssh i do not know any thing about it thank you